# How to get data in mat-cell and display in dialog form Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material-table

I am trying to make a mat-cell clickable and display form fields inside a mat-dialog and populating those fields with the data inside the mat-cell.

[image]

That is the current display that I have but I want it to be beside the mat-cell where it was clicked.

Here is the code in stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akbfr8

Any help will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the data to the modal using the `data` property on the config object.

```js
let dialogRef = dialog.open(YourDialog, {
  data: { name: 'austin' },
});
```

You can then use that data by injecting it into the Modal's constructor like so:

```js
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}',
})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { name: string }) { }
}
```

You can read more about it in the docs: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-

---

To have the dialog appear next to the cell that opened it you will need to set the position of the dialog. To do that define the `left` and `top` properties of the `position` property in the config object to be the right side of the cell.

```js
dialog.open(YourDialog, {
  position: {
    left: `${cellElement.offsetLeft + cellElement.offsetWidth}px`,
    top: `${cellElement.offsetTop + cellElement.offsetHeight}px`,
  }
})
```

I have updated your stackblitz to demo this behavior.

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5b2tpo)

Comment: Thanks! That's part 1 of the problem solved. Now can I place the dialog box beside whatever table cell I clicked on instead of having it show in the middle regardless of which cell i clicked?

Comment: @Paul I have updated my answer and provided a demo.